# SilverStripe 3.1.x How to Render a Page with a specific template from an Extension?

Tags: templates, module, controller, rendering, silverstripe

SilverStripe 3.1.x How to Render with a specific template from an Extension?

In SilverStripe 3.1.x, How can I make a Page render with a specific template from a Module Extension?  I'm working on a module that allows an administrator to change the display behaviour of a page at specific timeframes.  Making the page redirect works fine, but when it comes to rendering with a specific template, it seems to get ignored.

Here's an excerpt of the key parts of my code:

**mymodule/_config/mymodule.yml**

```
---
Name: mymodule
After:
- 'framework/*'
- 'cms/*'
---

Page_Controller:
  extensions:
    - MyPage_ControllerExtension
```

**mymodule/code/MyPage_ControllerExtension.php**

```
class MyPage_ControllerExtension extends Extension {

    public function onAfterInit() {

        //Render with MyTestTemplate.ss as a test
        return $this->owner->renderWith(array('MyTestTemplate', 'Page')); //Don't work

        //try redirecting
        //return $this->owner->redirect('http://google.com'); //Works fine 

    }

}
```

**mysite/code/Page.php**

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {

    private static $allowed_actions = array ();

    public function init() {
        parent::init();

    }

}
```

**themes/simple/templates/Layout/MyTestTemplate.ss**

```
<% include SideBar %>
<div class="content-container unit size3of4 lastUnit">
    <article>
        <h1>MY TEST TEMPLATE</h1>
        <div class="content">MY TEST CONTENT</div>
    </article>
</div>
```

After flushing the template cache, SilverStripe does not render Page.ss with MyTestTemplate.
How do I achieve that from the MyPage_ControllerExtension above?

When I debug by adding the parameter ?showtemplate=1 to the URL, I can see that SilverStripe does indeed get the content for MyTestTemplate, but in the end, it ignores it and the Layout/Page.ss template gets used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work for actions and index functions when default rendering is used (by returning array() or $this)

```
public function onAfterInit() {
    $this->owner->templates['index'] = array('MyTestTemplate', 'Page');
}
```

You could also use $this->owner->templates['*currentaction*'] if you want

But you'd have to add the following property to your **Page_Controller** class, because although it is checked from within the Controller class, it doesn't seem to be defined anywhere in the class chain (?):

```
public $templates;
```

Comment: Thanks, @Matimiz. Interesting approach.  We're almost there!  It's a shame that we cannot do this purely from the module without adding **public $templates** to the Page_Controller.  Also, I don't like the idea of having to explicitly set the array of templates per action.  Still thinking there has to be a better way...could the fact that $this->owner->renderWith() does not work from within the onAfterInit() method of the controller extension be a bug in the framework that requires a patch?

Comment: Seems to me that writing a standalone module like the one I am trying to write ought to be possible...  I'll try a few more things before accepting your previous answer that this may not be possible from a standalone module.  Of course, if I manage to get this to work, I'll post the solution here.  Thanks again.

Comment: You don't have to set templates for every action - it will use 'index' as a default. I also feel that $templates not being defined anywhere by default might be a bug - unless I'm missing something? so if that were to be solved you'd be in the clear...

Comment: Afaik Init() nor onAfterInit() are supposed to return the rendered contents, thats a job for the action handlers. Second: there are many modules that require you to add some little thing to either page, config or some template. As long as it's well documented...

Comment: Nice one @Martimiz - I think you are correct on both counts.  Adding 'public $templates' to the Page_Controller class is not so bad afterall... and I agree with you that $templates not being defined anywhere is most likely a bug.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the index() function in your (Data)Extension to return the rendered data:

```
public function index() {
    return $this->owner->renderWith(array('MyTestTemplate', 'Page')); 
}
```

**Note:** that would fail though, if the Page you're extending already has an index() function defined.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Martimiz.  Most of the pages have an index method and some have an index() method and several action methods too.  If an action is called, then index() will not be called.  I need a solution that will work regardless of whether an page action is called or not.

Comment: If your index() functions already return rendered templates, I don't think you can override that from within an Extension. So in this case a standalone module probably won't work, unless you make some alterations to the page as well...

Answer (score 0):

So, the final solution, from @Martimiz, which works whether or not an action is called is:

In the **Page_Controller** class in **mysite/code/Page.php**, add the following property as follows:

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {
    public $templates;
    ⋮
}
```

In **mymodule/code/MyPage_ControllerExtension.php**, add:

```
class MyPage_ControllerExtension extends Extension {

    public function onAfterInit() {
        $action = $this->owner->request->param('Action');
        if(!$action) $action = 'index';

        $this->owner->templates[$action] = array('MyTestTemplate', 'Page');
    }

}
```